# How to set specific widths of components in Codename One?

Tags: codenameone

I've been playing around with Codename One for a while now, but I can't seem to design a layout that I had planned with the layout managers provided. How should I go about designing the following layout?

I want a component on the left with a specific width, a component on the right with a specific width, and a center component that stretches or shrinks to the space that is leftover by the other two. If this was an html/css table, it would be something like:

```
<td style="width:50px;"></td><td style="width:auto;"></td><td style="width:50px;"></td>
```

`TableLayout` gets close, but the widths are defined in percentages only. `BorderLayout` and `GridLayout` bases the sizes on the prefered size of the largest component, but the `setPreferedSize()` method is deprecated, and `setSameWidth()` is suggested instead, but that doesn't seem to do what I need it to in this circumstance.

Comment: The question is "why" are you trying to do that?

Pixel sizes will look completely different between different resolutions/densities so hardcoding them makes very little sense. 

What is on the left/right side that needs it size preserved.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog The sides will have a portrait on top, in each container, and the reason why I want the width of the container to be hardcoded is so that it matches the width of the image so that other components with text below it know where to wrap their text as it reaches the image's imaginary borders on the x axis. I'm using uneditable TextArea s with custom UUID for the wrappable text. I set up this jsfiddle to illustrate the scenario: http://jsfiddle.net/22n2fq1e/ I can redesign it to avoid this need, but I imagine that there's merit in having that kind of control over a layout in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a component to have the right size for the image just place the image as an icon in a label and its preferred size will be the size of the image+padding which should give you exactly the effect you want by default.

Notice that the server sent images should differ in size based on the device DPI otherwise your app might look ridiculous on some devices. See this course for how we handle image requests to the server: https://www.udemy.com/build-mobile-ios-apps-in-java-using-codename-one/

Comment: Thanks for the extra material.